# Can I draw a horizontal line at specific number of range of values using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, range

I have data (from excel) with the y-axis as ranges (also calculated in excel) and the x-axis as cell counts and I would like to draw a horizontal line at a specific value in the range, like a reference line. I tried using `geom_hline(yintercept = 450)` but I am sure it is quite naive and does not work that way for a number in range. I wonder if there are any better suggestions for it :)

```
plot.new()
library(ggplot2)
d <- read.delim("C:/Users/35389/Desktop/R.txt", sep = "\t")
head(d)

d <- cbind(row.names(d), data.frame(d), row.names=NULL)
d
g <- ggplot(d, aes(d$CTRL,d$Bin.range))+ geom_col() 
g + geom_hline(yintercept = 450)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your expected result? it's not really clear...

Comment: ps: don't write `aes(d$CTRL,d$Bin.range)`, it's better to write it this way: `aes(CTRL, Bin.range)`. Even better if you specify x and y: `aes(x = CTRL, y = Bin.range)` :-)

Comment: also, remember that at the moment your Y axis is a character variable. Therefore, it doesn't get ordered in the right way in a ggplot. You see 50-99 is on top? Also that fact that it is a character var, implies you can't set a vertical line based on a number (450).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have a look at my comments.

Second, this is how I suggest you to proceed: don't calculate those ranges on Excel. Let ggplot do it for you.

Say, your data is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100, 0, 500))
head(df)
#>          x
#>1 322.76123
#>2  57.46708
#>3 223.31943
#>4 498.91870
#>5 155.05416
#>6 107.27830
```

Then you can make a plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
 geom_histogram(aes(x = x), 
                boundary = 0,
                binwidth = 50,
                fill = "steelblue",
                colour = "white") +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 450, colour = "red", linetype = 2, size = 1) +
 coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your data, but the following data frame is of a similar structure:

```r
d <- data.frame(CTRL = sample(100, 10), 
                Bin.range = paste(0:9 * 50, 0:9 * 50 + 49.9, sep = "-"))
```

The first thing to note is that your y axis does not have your ranges ordered correctly. You have `50-99.9` at the top of the y axis. This is because your ranges are stored as characters and ggplot will automatically arrange these alphabetically, not numerically. So you need to reorder the factor levels of your ranges:

```
d$Bin.range <- factor(d$Bin.range, d$Bin.range)
```

When you create your plot, don't use `d$Bin.range`, but instead just use `Bin.range`. `ggplot` knows to look for this variable in the data frame you have passed.

```r
g <- ggplot(d, aes(CTRL, Bin.range)) + geom_col()
```

If you want to draw a horizontal line, your two options are to specify the y axis label at which you want to draw the line (i.e. `yintercept = "400-449.9"`) or, which is what I suspect you want, use a numeric value of 9.5 which will put it between the top two values:

```
g + geom_hline(yintercept = 9.5, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much both of you for your help! Both codes work perfectly and fulfill my purpose :)